# Can not read files while reading from local storage

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I have a method which read files from a particular folder from my phone. I want to share those files via Gmail or other services. It works most of the time but sometime few files are not attached. I have tried so many ways but did not solve this issue yet. I will appreciate if anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance.
Here is the code sample.

```
try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/logs");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        attachments.clear();
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            Log.e("Report:", "-------------for loop start--------");
            for (File value : files) {
                Log.e("Report:", value.getName());
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "bd.com.cmed.pksf.provider", value);
                attachments.add(uri);
            }
            Log.e("Report:", "-------------for loop end--------");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Report:", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Here is the code that I added in AndroidManifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

   <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="bd.com.cmed.pksf.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Path provider file

```
    <paths>
     <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    </paths>
```

Here is the log that I have got.

```
    E/Report:: -------------for loop start--------
E/Report:: member_add.json
E/Report:: referral_add.json
E/Report:: -------------for loop end--------
E/Report:: -------------for loop start--------
E/Report:: member_add.json
E/Report:: referral_add.json
E/Report:: -------------for loop end--------
E/Report:: -------------for loop start--------
E/Report:: referral_add.json
E/Report:: -------------for loop end--------
E/Report:: -------------for loop start--------
E/Report:: referral_add.json
E/Report:: -------------for loop end--------
E/Report:: -------------for loop start--------
E/Report:: member_add.json
E/Report:: referral_add.json
E/Report:: -------------for loop end--------
```

Comment: `File file = new File(directory, value.getName());` Why are you doing that? Its the same as `File value`.

Comment: `File directory = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + LOG_WRITE_FILE_PATH);` That should better be `File directory = new File(root, LOG_WRITE_FILE_PATH);` And... We dont know what LOG_WRITE_FILE_PATH would be. It can not be a path. It should be a folder. Put it in your post please.

Comment: Your grant uri permissions and revoke make no sense.

Comment: `FileProvider skipping files ....` ? Who is skipping files?

Comment: @blackapps edited. Please check now.

Comment: You did not read my second comment?